# Which OS should be put on Raspi 4 with 2 GB RAM to use ROS?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a RasPi 4 with 2 GB RAM. I want to run ROS on it (preferably melodic) and run some SLAM packages on it.
Which OS should I put on it ? Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop or Ubuntu 18.04 Server or Ubuntu MATE 18.04 ?

Also any advices on the swap space as RAM (2GB) is less and the packages I'll be using would be heavy ?

TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367026/which-os-should-be-put-on-raspi-4-with-2-gb-ram-to-use-ros-?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2020-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have run the melodic navigation stack on an Ubuntu Mate 18.04-based image published by Ubiquity Robotics.

I felt a lack of CPU power, not memory. In some cases, I had to reduce the frequency in the configuration, etc. to make it work.

Be careful when building something from the source, not the package, as it failed if you don't create a swap area.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can tell what I have tried and worked.
I installed ubuntu mate 20.04 and ROS noetic.

you can try ubuntu 20.04, but I am not sure if it will give the best performance. I don't remember the reason for not trying 18.04, most probably because I read somewhere that its not recommended. Apologies, for not giving enough details.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [puru](https://answers.ros.org/users/28672/puru/) with karma: 31 on 2020-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2020-12-05**:
I agree. Ubuntu MATE would be lighter than the full fledged ubuntu desktop. That being said, I dont think 18 would give you any issues and you should be able to run melodic